# "Procedural" playground generation in c++ console application

Tags: c++, random, console, field

Adventure for learning basics and more in c++ (Total noob). Now i made a Playground Array for all the fields to visit, but when it comes to the rand() function in a for loop it repeats the Nummber so it's not random generated. Some ideads to fix this issue? Note that iam not very into the rand func.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
//**SETTINGS**
//Häufigkeit von field_type

#define VILLAGE 5
#define TOWN 2



int main()
{   
    //** THE PLAYGROUND ** 
    struct field {
        bool status;
        string field_type;

    };
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    field playground[5][5];

    //Playground Typen definition
    int village_counter = 0;
    int town_counter = 0;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y2 = 0;

    
    for (int counter = 0; counter < x * y; counter++) {

        int Nummer;
        srand(time(NULL));
        Nummer = rand() % 4 + 1;      // generates always the same number!


        switch (Nummer) {
        case 1:

            village_counter++;
            if (VILLAGE >= village_counter) {
                playground[x2][y2].field_type = "VILLAGE";

            }
            else {
                goto a_switch;
            }
            break;

        case 2:

            town_counter++;
            if (TOWN >= town_counter) {
                playground[x2][y2].field_type = "TOWN";
                
            }
            else {
                goto b_switch;
            }

            break;

        case 3:
            a_switch:
            playground[x2][y2].field_type = "GRASSLAND";
            break;
        case 4:
            b_switch:
            playground[x2][y2].field_type = "FOREST";
            break;
        }
        x2++;
        if (x2 == x) {
            x2 = 0;
            y2++;
        }

    }

    //For test usage of all Field's
    x2 = 0;
    y2 = 0;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < x * y; counter++) {
        cout << counter << ": Field_TYPE = " << playground[x2][y2].field_type << endl;
        x2++;
        if (x2 == x) {
            x2 = 0;
            y2++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, do never call `srand()` more than once in your application (especially not in a loop). It resets the seed of `rand()`. So, the `rand()` may return the same value consecutively multiple times (as it is probably called the same second repeatedly).

Comment: Btw. `rand()` and `srand()` are historical artifacts. Please, have a look at [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Since you want to learn C++, you should first decide which C++ standard you want to use: C++11, 17 or 20?
As a side note: You shouldn't use namespace std: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice
(Sorry for multiple comment edits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time` requests the current time in seconds as an integer.  if your program takes less than a second to execute, then you will "seed" the random number generator with the same value every time.  pseudo random number generators (i.e. your `rand()` call) return a deterministic series of values based on this state you seeded.

as @Scheff said, you're much better off just seeding once (probably at the beginning of the program) and then just calling `rand()` when you need it.  note that `srand` and `rand` are old historical artifacts from C, and you're much better off using more modern generators that come with recent C++ compilers

see the docs on [c++ random number generators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for more information